# Remove substring from string like lstrip but not as single characters

Tags: python, string

I have a string which only consists out of upper characters. So for example: `ABCABCABCBCA` but if I would use the .lstrip('ABC') method it would remove all characters which are `A, B or C` from the left of the string. I'd like to only remove `ABC` but for every `ABC` in this string.
So my desired output would be: `BCA`

Comment: A better example may be `ABCABCABCBCAABC` resulting in `BCAABC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace all occurrences of `ABC`, then use `replace` like the other answers. If you only want to remove from the left, then use a regex:

```py
import re

s = "ABCABCABCBCADABC"
re.sub("^(ABC)+", "", s) # 'BCADABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace` instead

```
>>> s = 'ABCABCABCBCA'
>>> s.replace('ABC', '')
'BCA'
```

Comment: This does help me thanks! But I'd like to only replace ABC occuring on the left side. So as soon as there is another combination as of the one provided I'd like my programm to stop removing ABC's

Comment: Didn't you say your expected output is `BCA`? Can you provide a few more examples if there is an edge case I missed?

Comment: Oh sure I'm sorry. So if I would have the string 'ABCABCBCACBAABCABC' I want it to remove all ABC's from the left so for this one the output would be: 'BCACBAABCABC'

Comment: Someone has already replied a working solution but thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.replace() method to remove every occurance of "ABC".

```
"ABCABCABCBCA".replace('ABC','')
```

Comment: Thank you too! But I'd like to only replace ABC occuring on the left side. So as soon as there is another combination as of the one provided I'd like my programm to stop removing ABC's